# Is there a nice way to route using EJS teamplate avoiding repetition with Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, ejs

Let's say that my app has two view: index.ejs, profile/index.ejs
I want to route using express code like below.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

/* GET profile page. */
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile/index');
});
```

should both two ejs files have bootstrap link?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If the answer is yes, whenever I want to render another page, should I reload style and js file from CDN?

I mean, is there a nice way to keep common contents when I change my EJS template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1). use partials and include them in every page.

2). If you don't like including the partials in each page then you can use [express-ejs-layouts](https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts) or [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals)

For the first approach we can have a partials directory that will contain all the partials we need.

[image: partials directory]

And here are our partials

```
//partials/head.ejs
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>EJS Template</title>
<link ref="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

This scipt.js can include all the scripts that you want to include.

```
//partials/script.js   

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>
```

Let's say we want to include these partials in index.ejs then all we need to do is to simply use `<% include partial %>` and we are good to go.

```
 // index.ejs
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <% include partials/head %>
      </head>
      <body class="container">

        <header>
          <% include partials/header %>
        </header>

        <main>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>This is great</h1>
            <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
          </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
           <% include partials/footer %>
        </footer>
        <% include partials/script %>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

No. You can do this easily by adding scripts and css that are used for whole application into different `EJS` file.

For example.

Create file called `header.ejs` and add in it all links and scripts.

Then in your templates just include this file, with this piece of code

```
<head>
   <% include header.ejs %>
   //IN HERE you can add page specific scripts or links
</head>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: does it download css files again and again whenever I move from page to page?

Comment: It shouldn't. Browsers checks to see if the scripts or links somehow changes, if not they will use cached version. You can check it, by using dev console in chrome for example. To see if browser will take cache version or try to load again.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!